# Google API OAuth 2.0 in WinRT Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm currently struggling with implementing Google API OAuth in a WinRT Metro Javascript app. The problem is that I cannot [provide](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) any working redirect_uri that works with a Metro App. The urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob URL for installed apps is not working and I cannot imagine a way to host a HttpListener in a Javascript app that could handle the redirect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
START URI = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id= Ur Client ID &redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

End URI =https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?
Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions.useTitle, startURI, endURI)
   .then(function (result) {
}
```

Above is the some glimpse of my code so I paste here.. You may try this it will help you.